# Checklist using whiptail - Why I can't run multi commands?

Tags: bash, whiptail

This code will run only for the first match because of the lines under functions: **service httpd start** but it will display echo from all functions if I remove all ssh... lines. 
Could someone explain it to me what is happening and maybe some solution how I can use it.

```
#!/bin/bash
 function s1 {
        echo "running 1 "
        ssh user@server_1_IP service httpd start
}
    function s2 {
        echo "running 2"
        ssh user@server_2_IP service httpd start
} 
function s3 {
        echo "running 3"
        ssh user@server_3_IP service httpd start
}
whiptail --title "Test" --checklist --separate-output "Choose:" 20 78 15 \
"Server1" "" on \
"Server2" "" on \
"Server3" "" on 2>results

while read choice  
do
        case $choice in
                Server1) s1
                ;;
                Server2) s2
                ;;
                Server3) s3
                ;;
                *)
                ;;
        esac
done < results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `stdin` that comes from file `results` is given both to `while read ...` and to `ssh` (in `s1`, `s2` and `s3`). `ssh` will eat whatever was not read by `read` in the first loop.

Try saving `stdin` before the loop for later use with ssh:

```
exec {stdin}<&0
while read choice  
do
        case $choice in
                Server1) s1 <&$stdin ;;
                Server2) s2 <&$stdin ;;
                Server3) s3 <&$stdin ;;
        esac
done < results
```

Or use `< /dev/null` if you don't need stdin in `ssh`.

Comment: I'm new here. I accepted your answer do I have to do something more? To give you some points or something?

Comment: @Shimpu Welcome, then! See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work You can also upvote the answer when you have enough reputation